# Add rounded corner to a group of divs

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a simple horizontal div with a few colored children:

```css
.bar {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  
  border-radius: 20px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="segment" style="width: 150px; background: red;"></div>
  <div class="segment" style="width: 100px; background: blue;"></div>
  <div class="segment" style="width: 5px; background: green;"></div>
</div>
```

I want to try make the `.bar` div have rounded corners but can't see an obvious way to do it. I know this way:

```
.segment {
    &.first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 25px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    }

    &.last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 25px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work if one of the `.segment`'s is too small, as is the case in my snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put border radius on bar and hide the overflow:

```css
.bar {
  display: inline-flex;  /* make inline so it is only as wide as children */
  height: 90px;
  
  border-radius: 25px;  
  overflow: hidden;   /* add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="segment" style="width: 150px; background: red;"></div>
  <div class="segment" style="width: 100px; background: blue;"></div>
  <div class="segment" style="width: 5px; background: green;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how hiding the overflow makes it work? It worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Because the content inside the div is overflowing the rounded corners, it makes it look like there are no rounded corners on the parent.  Hiding the overflow makes the corners show up so to speak - ie it stops the child content overflowing the parent boundary